# HTML 5 video player not working when unmuted

Tags: html5-video

I'm currently developing a website locally. I have implemented an html 5 video player, but the strange thing is that this video only works when muted. When I remove the unmuted property, the video doesn't start to play and I got a black video screen (https://prnt.sc/vk5v93). Any idea why that is?

```
<video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/video/video.mov'; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers block autoplay when the video is not muted nowadays. It's most complicated on [Chrome, where the browser will block or not depending on the user's "engagement" with the site](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). You have to assume autoplay with sound won't necessarily work.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Screen is black because frame 1 is probably all black. The alternative approach is to add ```controls``` to the video tag so that you users can start/stop.